# How to write time sequence length to predict next value using LSTM in python

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, time, keras, lstm

Here I have dataset with three input named X1, X2, X3. So here I want to predict X1 value in every 60 minute.

Here I measure values not in every 60 minutes. Due to that matter I resample data in every 5 minutes to reduce the error.

So then I want to predict my next value in every 60 minutes. So that I wrote the code for time sequence.

So here time sequence= 12.
Due to resampling the data into every 5 minute, for 60 minute it is 12,`12*5 = 60 minutes.`

I used lstm model to predict the value of x1. 
When I wrote the code for predict the value in every 60 minute it gave me an error `Error when checking input: expected lstm_1_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (12, 1)`

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Here is my code:

```
sequence_timestep = 12
last_sequence_train = x_train_n[-1]

pred1 = []

def sequence_constructor():
   if len(pred1) >= sequence_timestep:
     new_sequence = pred1[-x_train:]
   else:
     splitter = sequence_timestep - len(pred1)
     part_1 = last_sequence_train[-splitter:]
     new_sequence = np.append(part_1,pred1) #Concatenate 2 list
 new_sequence = np.array(new_sequence)
 return new_sequence  


for i in range(288):
 new_sequence = sequence_constructor()
 new_prediction = model.predict(new_sequence)
 pred1.append(new_prediction)
```

Error:

[image]

[My csv file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WWq1qhqi4bGzNir_svQV7VstBkGbocToipPCY83Cclc/edit?usp=drive_web&ouid=113105666949273151155)